# Ruby Selenium WebDriver wait for keypress

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

SO. How I can do next?:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 1000) 
wait.until{
  //  here insert code
  //  for "catching" keypress
  driver.quit // e.g.
}
```

I need "set pause" for test until I shall press any key ( ENTER, e.g.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a code as below :

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 1000) 
wait.until do
    # you can chose any key instead of :control      
    driver.action.key_down(:control).perform.nil?
end
# to release the key :control
driver.action.key_up(:control).perform
```

Look the documentation of [`key_down`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html#key_down-instance_method) :

> Performs a modifier key press. Does not release the modifier key - subsequent interactions may assume it's kept pressed. Note that the modifier key is never released implicitly - either `#key_up(key)` or `#send_keys(:null)` must be called to release the modifier.